# Android In-app billing Phonegap 1.0

Tags: android, cordova, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I know I already asked related question but now it's a bit different situation.

I found out that it is possible to implement Android in-app billing in Phonegap project. At least with the final 1.0 release. But it looks like it requires really a lot of code (both native Java and Javascript). Too much work for this task for one developer.

Does anyone already did plugin for Phonegap to use Android in-app billing?
Or maybe someone developing it right now?

New PayPal plugin is good and it works well but I also should implement native Android payments somehow.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just release my plugin prototype in github. I tested only with the testing product ids provided by Google. Take a look and fork it if you want: https://github.com/luoihoc/CallbackBillingPlugin

Answer (score 3):

I have just released an **in app billing plugin** for cordova 2.0:
https://github.com/poiuytrez/AndroidInAppBilling

Update: I have upgraded the plugin to the In App Billing api v3.

Comment: Hi there, How can I download the plugin. I do not see it when I clone the repository.

Comment: Make sure to check out the billing branch.

Comment: What is the status of this plugin? It hasn't yet been merged into the official repository

Comment: Waiting for it to be merged. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/pull/782.  I don't know what they are waiting for.......